# How do I scale a 8x8 pixel art Bitmap to be 100 pixels width and height without any distortion in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, pixel

I'm making a game that is Pixel-based in Android. I have several 8x8 sprites that need to be resized to fit on a 100x100 area. As a test to see if it would work, I tried to just make the image fill the entire canvas. It kind of worked, but it made the 8x8 sprite turn into a 12x12 sprite, making the pixels look really odd and distorted. Here's what I have so far:

```
        Bitmap grass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small);
        Paint configuration = new Paint();
        configuration.setDither(false);
        configuration.setAntiAlias(false);
        Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix();
        myMatrix.postScale(canvas.getWidth() / grass.getWidth(), canvas.getWidth() / grass.getHeight());
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(grass, 0, 0, grass.getWidth(), grass.getHeight(), myMatrix, false);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work on bitmaps then you simply can't. You'd minimize the distortion by scaling up by non-fractional factor so each pixed would be repeated same number of times (i.e. image 10x10 to 20x20 is scaled by factor of two, but 8x8 to 12x12 is 1,5 so no luck). The solution would be to have all assets in vector form (i.e. SVG) and then render them on run-time according to device density and other specs or prepare separate assets for various type of devices (which would blow application size up a bit)

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to parse through each pixel to get the pixel color and then draw a Rects for each pixel if this won't work...

Comment: This would be pointless. Scaling up will always cause a distortion as you are interpolating source bitmap into bigger bitmap (in other words you are making more data from less data). In fact in case like yours (1,5 factor) you should rather enable anti-aliasing than keep it off. it would make image bit more blurry but less crappy. Anyway - there's no better solution than going vector (or creating separate assets and avoid upscaling)

Comment: No-no. I mean that I could get the first pixel in the Bitmap's color, (ie. blue), and then use some getPixelColor or something, then make a new Rect and make the Rect's color the same as the pixel's color, and the dimensions to be 1/8 of Canvas size. Then keep going for each pixel until all pixels are parsed. Then again, this could make drawing REALLY slow, so this could probably never work.

Comment: you can read pixels but what for, really? You are scaling 8x8 to 12x12. you need all pixels scaled. how do you expect 1 pixel to stretch nicely to 1,5 pixel - there's no half of pixel so it's either scaled to 2 or stays at 1, and that's what causes the issue

Comment: I don't want it scaled to 12,12. I need it actually scaled to 480, 480. Sorry for being unclear. I should've mentioned 480, but for some reason I didn't.

Comment: Again: it is matter of factor. Scaling from 8x8 to 480x480 should be (pixelate) but fine - it's 60 times bigger. Or I do not really getting your problem? :)